# How to find the closest midnight to a datetime in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to take a long list of datetimes and output a new column that gives me the closest midnight. For example, I would like the following outputs (dates and times in separate columns).

```
date        time

10/1/2021   23:55 --> 10/1

10/2/2021   21:15 --> 10/2

10/3/2021   18:34 --> 10/3

10/5/2021   0:00 --> 10/4

10/6/2021   5:32 --> 10/5

10/7/2021   0:19 --> 10/6
```

I imagine doing something along the lines of if time <12:00, output date - 1, but I am getting invalid syntax.

```
ts = pd.to_datetime('12:00')

df['closest_midnight'] = df['Start Date']

df['closest_midnight'] = [df['closest_midnight'] - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='D')] if df['Start Time'] < ts
```

Comment: Have you tried `astral` module?

Comment: Use `pd.Series.dt.round` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html

Comment: or `pd.Timestamp.round` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.round.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use timedelta for this:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

mask = pd.to_timedelta(df['time']+':00').lt('12h')

df['closest_midnight'] = df['date'].mask(mask, df['date']-pd.to_timedelta('1d'))
```

Output:

```
        date   time closest_midnight
0 2021-10-01  23:55       2021-10-01
1 2021-10-02  21:15       2021-10-02
2 2021-10-03  18:34       2021-10-03
3 2021-10-05   0:00       2021-10-04
4 2021-10-06   5:32       2021-10-05
5 2021-10-07   0:19       2021-10-06
```